Camera not working if used in homescreen app IOS
I want to scan a QR code from my website and i'm using the html5-qrcode js library.
It is working properly from safari or whatever browser I use it in.
It asks for permissions, then makes you select the camera you want to use and finally shows you the preview of the camera
If I add my website to the homescreen this behavious changes...
I can click the button to allow permissions to use the camera but after a few seconds it looks like the permit I just granted gets denied and the camera just won't start.
This seems to only affect IOS devices since it's working on an Android device I used to test this feature.
You can test this behaviour on this website scanApp
Currently my IOS version is 17.5.1 (latest at current date)

I tried adding the meta tag:
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

But nothing really changed...
Looking forward to a solution :/

I am having the same problem, this was working before 17.5.1 so I think it's something apple have done

Actually, I just did a soft reset and now it works. To soft reset: tap volume up, tap volume down, then hold the power button until apple logo appears. I have two apps - one using the quagga2 barcode scanner lib, the other using the ShapeDetection api. Can confirm that both are working now when added to home screen

@myleftshoe That's crazy, i turned off my phone and turned it back on and it still wouldn't work but the hard reset you suggested worked perfectly fine
Post this as a solution if you want and I will flag it as correct answer.

Even as a main Apple user I gotta admit that it's insane that people will have to do a hard reset to make such a simple thing work fine

Looks like this issue can be fixed by soft resetting your device
To do so follow these steps:
1 - Tap volume up button
2 - Tap volume down button
3 - Long press power button until apple logo shows

This solved the issue for me
